# How to use css to set svg hover color?

Tags: css, svg

I hope the second square to be discolored , ask how to do it

```css
rect{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  fill: #ff0;
 }
rect:hover{
  fill: #f0f;
}
use:hover{
  fill: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="140" height="300">
 <defs>
     <rect id="rect"/>
 </defs>
<rect/>
<use xlink:href="#rect" y="120"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the fill from the `def` and use apply to to the `use`.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;  
}

.green {
  fill:green;
}

.green:hover {
  fill:lightgreen;
}

.blue {
  fill:blue
}

.blue:hover {
  fill:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" class="hidden">
  <defs>
    <rect id="rect" width="100" height="100" />
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" class="box green" />
</svg>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" class="box blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer